# Ambiguous column when executing SQL Server function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

SQL Fiddle is currently down regarding SQL Server code, so here is a dropbox link to a `.txt` containing the `DDL` to create the schema I'm using:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6si4r37449q3ajb/DDL.txt?dl=0

I'm studying for an exam and struggling with an example problem.

*Create a function to calculate the total cost of a software package (given the software package’s name) installed in each department in the last three years. Check whether the name is accurate.*

Here's my solution:

```
 create function total_cost_of_sofpack_in_lst3yrs
    (@pack_name varchar(20))
 returns table
 as
     return(
        select sum(packcost) as total_pk_cost, location
        from package
        inner join software on package.PACK = software.PACK
        inner join pc on software.tagnum = pc.tagnum
        where package.PACKNAME = @pack_name 
          and software.INSTDATE > dateadd(year, -3, getdate())
        group by pc.location)
     go

     select dbo.total_cost_of_sofpack_in_lst3yrs('Manta') as R
```

The statement to create the function passes, but when I try to execute it via a test scenario, I get the following error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.total_cost_of_sofpack_in_lst3yrs", or the name is
>   ambiguous.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `Select * From dbo.total_cost_of_sofpack_in_lst3yrs('Manta')`  Your function returns a `TABLE`, so you need to query it like a `TABLE`.

Comment: You've created a table valued function so you need to `select columns from it` you're calling it like a scalar function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the return type is `TABLE` from the function, you need to call as

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.total_cost_of_sofpack_in_lst3yrs('Manta')
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your question is to

> Create a function to calculate the total cost of a software package
>   (given the software package’s name) installed in each department in
>   the last three years.

perhaps you should re-write your function as a scalar function?

```
 create function total_cost_of_sofpack_in_lst3yrs(@pack_name varchar(20))

 RETURNS decimal(10, 2)  -- or whatever data type 'packcost' is...
 as
 return(
    select sum(packcost)as total_pk_cost
    from package
    inner join software on package.PACK=software.PACK
    inner join pc on software.tagnum=pc.tagnum
    where package.PACKNAME=@pack_name 
    and software.INSTDATE > dateadd(year, -3, getdate())
    group by pc.location
 )
 go

 select dbo.total_cost_of_sofpack_in_lst3yrs('Manta') as R
```